# Use Bootstrap col-md-4 grid, but it breaks

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

i want to use 3 colums (col-md-4) nested in a col-md-9. For that i use the following code:

```
<?php if (have_posts()){ ?>
<section class="container container-fluid">  
      <div class="row" id="ajaxPostContainer">
        <div class="col-md-9">

        <?php
        ini_set("display_errors", 1);

        while (have_posts()){
            the_post();
        $post_uri           = get_permalink();
        $post_image         = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()) );

        $content            = get_the_content();
        $content            = preg_replace('/<a href=\"(.*?)\">(.*?)<\/a>/', "\\2", $content);            
    ?>

     <div class="col-md-4" data-categories="" style="" >
        <a href="<?=$post_uri?>" title="">

                <?php if($post_image !== false){ ?>
                 <article>
                <img src="<?=$post_image?>" class="img-responsive" style="width: 100%;" />
                <?php } ?>
                <h3><?=the_title('', '', false)?></h3>
                <div class="entry">
                <p><?=$content?></p>

        </article>
        <hr />
        </a>
        </div>   




    <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <?php dynamic_sidebar("single-post"); ?>
        </div><!-- sidebar --> 
    </div>  

</div></div>
```

But in some line the 3 colums of col-md-4 break. Why? For example on this page:

https://www.immvestwolf.de/blog/eigentumswohnungen-leipzig

Comment: yes, i changed it

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the `col-md-4`s in a `div` with class `row`? Open it right after `<div class="col-md-9">` and close it after `<?php } ?>`.

Comment: thanks for your answer... this is not working. the columns still break

Comment: Post the rendered HTML, not the PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the site it seems it is caused by the fact that all your columns have a different height. Try adding `height: 800px` and you'll see it now works. Also looks better ;)

To make this look even nicer, make sure to cut off the text beyond a certain length and you can reduce the height somewhat.

Comment: with the height that works! how can i cutt off the text beyond a certain length?

Comment: That's a whole other topic. Google `max-height`, `overflow-y` and `text-overflow` + CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `<div class="row">` to wrap your 3 `col-md-4` divs inside `<div class="col-md-9">`. This will reduce some padding so that there is no line break:

Example (need to test it on your end):

```
<?php if (have_posts()){ ?>
    <section class="container container-fluid">  
      <div class="row" id="ajaxPostContainer">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="row">
                <?php
                ini_set("display_errors", 1);

                while (have_posts()){
                    the_post();
                    $post_uri           = get_permalink();
                    $post_image         = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()) );

                    $content            = get_the_content();
                    $content            = preg_replace('/<a href=\"(.*?)\">(.*?)<\/a>/', "\\2", $content);            
                    ?>


                    <div class="col-md-4" data-categories="" style="" >
                        <a href="<?=$post_uri?>" title="">

                            <?php if($post_image !== false){ ?>
                               <article>
                                <img src="<?=$post_image?>" class="img-responsive" style="width: 100%;" />
                            <?php } ?>
                            <h3><?=the_title('', '', false)?></h3>
                            <div class="entry">
                                <p><?=$content?></p>

                            </article>
                            <hr />
                        </a>
                    </div>   


                <?php } ?>
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="sidebar">
                <?php dynamic_sidebar("single-post"); ?>
            </div><!-- sidebar --> 
        </div>  

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. But when i add <div class="row"> in the loop i does not work. i see one column per line....

Comment: You can try to move it to be just inside the `<div class="col-md-9">` so that it is not in your loop, I edited my answer